# How get wkinterfacelabel text?

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchapp

watchkit WKİnterfaceLabel not supported.

```
@IBOutlet weak var wklabel: WKInterfaceLabel!   
var text = wklabel.text //error
println(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't retrieve the current text from a [`WKInterfaceLabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceLabel_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014960-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4) as the class only provides methods for setting text and colour. You would have to store the text in your own string property before setting it on the label.